# How to save instance state of a Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, onsaveinstancestate

I have an activity and 5 layouts.
In the onCreate I setContentView for the start page layout and then through a button i skip to another layout. The problem appears when i rotate the screen. It turns back to the start page. What I have to do to keep the same layout when I rotate the screen?
This is what I have in onCreate :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(**R.layout.activity_main**);
```

By clicking the start button it goes to the first method :

```
public void firstQuestion(View view) {
    //here we change the layout. it will be the same for every new question
    setContentView(**R.layout.first_question**);
```

.....some code and then

```
 final ImageView forward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.forward);
    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (time_is_up) resultsDialog(view);//if time is up we jump to results
            else secondQuestion(view);          //if not we skip to the next question
        }
    });
```

then second question :

```
public void secondQuestion(View view) {
    setContentView(**R.layout.second_question**);
```

and so on.

Comment: You'd probably be better off with a `ViewFlipper` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your last Activity state and reuse it when recreating the activity:

```
int layoutId = R.layout.activity_main;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putInt("layoutId", layoutId);
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        layoutId = savedInstanceState.getInt("layoutId", R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    setContentView(layoutId);
}

public void firstQuestion(View view) {
    layoutId = R.layout.first_question;
    setContentView(layoutId);
}
```